# How to insert multiple images directly to the sql database?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a database in which contain product details The product code, name etc are the columns, I have the product images in the system in a folder I need to add the images directly to the database according to the proper rows regarding the product code, The product code and images are sam, the product code is like 110-1,110-2 etc, and image names are 110-1jpg,110-2jpg etc I have a program but its not updating all the rows pls help

```
DECLARE @CODE varchar

DECLARE image_cursor CURSOR FOR

SELECT CODE FROM MyMast WHERE img IS NULL

OPEN image_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM image_cursor

INTO @CODE;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @imagePath VARCHAR(255)

SET @imagePath = 'D:\images\' + RTRIM(LTRIM(@CODE)) + '.jpg'

SET @sql = 'UPDATE Mymast'

SET @sql = @sql + 'SET img = (SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET( BULK ''' + @imagePath + ''', Single_Blob) AS Picture), SET PictureFileName = ' + @imagepath

SET @sql = @sql + 'WHERE CODE = ''' + @CODE + ''';'

BEGIN TRY

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

END CATCH

FETCH NEXT FROM image_cursor

INTO @CODE;

END

CLOSE image_cursor;

DEALLOCATE image_cursor;

SELECT CODE, img FROM MyMast WHERE img IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Check this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/47c8edc1-8cad-4a24-a09a-3fc0c943325c/bulk-insert-multiple-files-tsql

Comment: I have added a new code, but its show error while converting codes, my codes are like '110-1'

Answer (score -1):

DECLARE @CODE int
DECLARE image_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT CODE FROM MyMast WHERE img IS NULL
OPEN image_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM image_cursor 
INTO @CODE;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @imagePath NVARCHAR(255)
    SET @imagePath = 'D:\images\'+ RTRIM(LTRIM('12')) + '.jpg'
    SET @sql = 'UPDATE MyMast '
    SET @sql = @sql + 'SET img = (SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET( BULK ''' + @imagePath + ''', Single_Blob) AS img) '
    SET @sql = @sql + 'WHERE CODE = ' + STR(@CODE)

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

END CATCH   

FETCH NEXT FROM image_cursor 
INTO @CODE;
```

END
CLOSE image_cursor;
DEALLOCATE image_cursor;

SELECT CODE, img FROM MyMast WHERE img IS NOT NULL

I have tried this code, but it shows error in convertion of nvarchar to float, code is in the format 110-1